# I Can't Figure Out This Regular Expression

Tags: regex

I am working on this simple regular expression. I am using a regular expression to clean some data. I have a list of characters that are allowed. I then need the regex to match anything that is not in the list of characters that are allowed. Sounds complicated but it is really simple. Here is the regex I put together:

```
(?i)^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\.\(\"\'\:\;\%\/\-]*$
```

The characters allowed are :

```
a-z
A-Z
0-9
\s
.
(
)
"
'
:
;
%
/
-
_
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong as my regex dosent seem to return anything at all

Comment: You forgot `)` in your character class.

Comment: Wait... Did you specify case-insensitivity (`(?i)`), then put `a-zA-Z`? Why? Also you didn't really specify `_` like you thought you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wanted `[^` (start a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)), but have `^[` (a character class after a [string beginning](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)).

```
(?i)[^a-z0-9\s.()"':;%/\-_]
```

will match every character that is not allowed.

Comment: This seems to kind of work. It does return the - in my data however - is a character that is allowed. There is a character that is from another language (not English) that I am trying to get a return for hence the reason for making the regex in a way so I can list the allowed characters

Comment: @Allsystems Escape the `-`. Also the answer should have it escaped too, else it's matching `/-_` as a range.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys. I managed to fix it. The answer from Bergi is the correct answer. I just added the other allowed characters. Great place StackOverFlow. First time I used it and the replies have been so fast. Bergi I don't know how to add "rep" otherwise I would do for your help

Comment: @Allsystems: Oops, I forgot to escape the `-` - which is the only one that actually needs to be escaped of all the characters in your list.